# Issue with Ratio and Maximize in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I think the cause is with the Ratio, but I am not certain, this appeared on my project and I can't find a solution, So this is my last draw on this issue before trying to blend it in my game and try to adjust it from there.

Whenever Maximize On Play is On, The ratio or camera tends to zoom or pan on the left side, I ignored this thinking it was an issue with my side but by building the pre-alpha on my game it became an annoying issue

[Without Maximize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuLMv.jpg)

[With Maximize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qReM3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your code or the camera properties, But I'm pretty sure you could fix this using **Cinemachine**.

[Check this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=537B1kJp9YQ) tutorial by unity

Comment: There wasn't any script that changed the camera or caused anything to change it wasn't a script issue or something caused by a script that's why I said I am not certain of the issue and assume it has something to do with Ratio since the ratio is the only thing that affected it because of Maximize showing the issue, and the only difference between Maximize and not is Ratio as far as I'm aware of, I'll try Cinemachine nevertheless